# Is there a way to assign keyboard shortcuts for specific applications in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts

When I work in Ubuntu, I have a couple of open applications: IDE, a terminal, a browser.
Is there a way to define keyword shortcuts to switch between them, e.g. `Start key + B` for browser, `Start key + T` for the terminal? Is there are a plugin for that?

I know that `Start key + Tab` switches between windows, but I would like something that goes directly to the application I want.

Comment: KDE or Gnome? For KDE, see [this example](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90567/quickly-launch-any-app-in-kde-with-a-shortcut).

Comment: Thanks, but GNOME

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Easily](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-shortcuts-set.html.en)!

- Press <kbd>System</kbd> and type *keyb*.
- Select *Keyboard*.
- At the bottom of the *long* list are the *custom shortcuts* you create.
- Press the **+** symbol and type the name of the application in the *command* edit box. For example, to start the *Firefox* , enter *firefox*. **N.B.** This is case sensitive, i.e. "firefox" must be all lower case.
  To check an application's filename, you can type it in *Terminal* to run the app. You can also use Ubuntu's *System Monitor* to see the filename while the application is running.
- Applications can also be added under [*wine*](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine). For example, to run the (nominally) Windows application  *IrfanView*, enter *wine [path]/i_view64.exe* as the command. In a dual-boot PC, it can even be run that way if it's in the Windows NTFS *Program Files* folder.

A tutorial is at [GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/step-by-step-guide-to-add-custom-keyboard-shortcut-in-ubuntu/).

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that. 
But every time a shortcut is pressed a new application is started. I wanted to switch between existing applications.

Comment: As in Windows, Alt-Tab and Shift-Alt-Tab switch to the next or previous running application. Hit it multiple time if you have to choose amongst many. BTW, anyone know who was first with that shortcut? Windows, Linux? Maybe even Atari or other 8-bit OS?

Answer (score 0):

[Hotkeys Popup](https://github.com/mipmip/gnome-shell-extensions-hotkeys-popup) (GitHub)

This Gnome extension (Gnome 40,41,42 and 43) will give you the ability to add keyboard shortcuts.

From *settings -> keyboard -> keyboard shortcuts -> additional keyboard shortcuts* you can add a keyboard shortcut for a command.

Comment: How is this better than accepted answer?

Comment: Since the Gnome Extension page you linked had no real info on the extension or its usage, I changed the link to the actual GitHub page of the extension. The GitHub page says adding new shortcuts happens with a JSON file. As you claim there's a different way, you should edit the answer and add relevant screenshots showing the process.